# xamarin forms uri image not resizing

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms project, I'm trying to resize an image from a uri. Problem is anything I try to resize the image is not working. I've tried adjusting the following:
heightrequest, widthrequest, Fill, fillAndExpand, placing it inside of another stacklayout ect. Ive tried using a local image from the resources folder and the image resizes fine, so this is only an issue with an image from a uri.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this works, but placing the image inside of a grid, then setting the desired size in the grid resizes the image.

Comment: *"Not sure why this works, but..."* now there's a phrase I've used time and again during Xamarin development.